# ValueError: Shapes (None, 86) and (None, 88) are incompatible

Tags: python, valueerror

I am new to python and building models and i tried to build a model that recognizes musical notes from an audio
and when I run this code:

```
import os
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
import librosa
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from datetime import datetime

# Load metadata for training and testing
df_train = pd.read_csv("C:/Datasets/piano_notes_Dataset/88notesMetadata_train.csv")
df_test = pd.read_csv("C:/Datasets/piano_notes_Dataset/piano_notes_test_metadata.csv")

# Feature extraction function

def Feature_extractor(file):
    audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(file, res_type='kaiser_fast')
    mfccs_features = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
    mfccs_scaled_features = np.mean(mfccs_features.T, axis=0)
    return mfccs_scaled_features

# Extract features and labels for training data
extracted_features_train = []
for index, row in tqdm(df_train.iterrows()):
    file_name = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('C:/Datasets/piano_notes_Dataset/piano-88-notes_train/'), str(row["FileName"]))
    final_class_label = row["Class"]
    data = Feature_extractor(file_name)
    extracted_features_train.append([data, final_class_label])

# Convert to DataFrame
extracted_features_df_train = pd.DataFrame(extracted_features_train, columns=['features', 'class'])

# Extract features and labels for testing data
extracted_features_test = []
for index, row in tqdm(df_test.iterrows()):
    file_name = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('C:/Datasets/piano_notes_Dataset/Filtered/'), str(row["FileName"]))
    final_class_label = row["Class"]
    data = Feature_extractor(file_name)
    extracted_features_test.append([data, final_class_label])

# Convert to DataFrame
extracted_features_df_test = pd.DataFrame(extracted_features_test, columns=['features', 'class'])

@keras_export("keras.utils.to_categorical")
def to_categorical(y, num_classes=None, dtype="float32"):
    """Converts a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix.

    E.g. for use with `categorical_crossentropy`.

    Args:
        y: Array-like with class values to be converted into a matrix
            (integers from 0 to `num_classes - 1`).
        num_classes: Total number of classes. If `None`, this would be inferred
          as `max(y) + 1`.
        dtype: The data type expected by the input. Default: `'float32'`.

    Returns:
        A binary matrix representation of the input as a NumPy array. The class
        axis is placed last.

    Example:

    >>> a = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical([0, 1, 2, 3], num_classes=4)
    >>> print(a)
    [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 1. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 1. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

    >>> b = tf.constant([.9, .04, .03, .03,
    ...                  .3, .45, .15, .13,
    ...                  .04, .01, .94, .05,
    ...                  .12, .21, .5, .17],
    ...                 shape=[4, 4])
    >>> loss = tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(a, b)
    >>> print(np.around(loss, 5))
    [0.10536 0.82807 0.1011  1.77196]

    >>> loss = tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(a, a)
    >>> print(np.around(loss, 5))
    [0. 0. 0. 0.]
    """
    y = np.array(y, dtype="int")
    input_shape = y.shape

    # Shrink the last dimension if the shape is (..., 1).
    if input_shape and input_shape[-1] == 1 and len(input_shape) > 1:
        input_shape = tuple(input_shape[:-1])

    y = y.reshape(-1)
    if not num_classes:
        num_classes = np.max(y) + 1
    n = y.shape[0]
    categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes), dtype=dtype)
    categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
    output_shape = input_shape + (num_classes,)
    categorical = np.reshape(categorical, output_shape)
    return categorical
# Convert labels to categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

LE = LabelEncoder()
y_train = to_categorical(LE.fit_transform(extracted_features_df_train['class']))
y_test = to_categorical(LE.transform(extracted_features_df_test['class']))

# Prepare features
X_train = np.array(extracted_features_df_train['features'].tolist())
X_test = np.array(extracted_features_df_test['features'].tolist())

# Display shapes
print("Shape Of X_train:", X_train.shape)
print("Shape Of X_test:", X_test.shape)
print("Shape Of y_train:", y_train.shape)
print("Shape Of y_test:", y_test.shape)

print("Unique classes in training set:", extracted_features_df_train['class'].unique())
print("Unique classes in testing set:", extracted_features_df_test['class'].unique())
# Model configuration

num_labels = y_train.shape[1]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(40,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(200))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(200))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(num_labels))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

# Model training
num_epochs = 100
num_batch_size = 32
#Save The Model
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='C:/Datasets/piano_notes_Dataset/audio_classification.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
start = datetime.now()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=num_batch_size, epochs=num_epochs,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[checkpointer])

# Model evaluation
test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test Accuracy:", test_accuracy[1])

# Example of testing on a new audio file
filename = "C:/Datasets/piano_notes_Dataset/Filtered/As1_N.wav"
audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(filename, res_type='kaiser_fast')
mfccs_features = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
mfccs_scaled_features = np.mean(mfccs_features.T, axis=0)
mfccs_scaled_features = mfccs_scaled_features.reshape(1, -1)

predicted_label = np.argmax(model.predict(mfccs_scaled_features), axis=-1)
prediction_class = LE.inverse_transform(predicted_label)
print("Predicted Class:", prediction_class)
```

this error occurred, I checked the labels of my metadata and they are ok- 88 unique classes.
what could be the problem?

I needed the code to give the prediction result of this audio
filename = "C:/Datasets/piano_notes_Dataset/Filtered/As1_N.wav"
Thank you for your help.

Edit:
when I run the lines:

```
print("Shape Of X_train:", X_train.shape)
print("Shape Of X_test:", X_test.shape)
print("Shape Of y_train:", y_train.shape)
print("Shape Of y_test:", y_test.shape)
print("Unique classes in training set:", extracted_features_df_train['class'].unique())
print("Unique classes in testing set:", extracted_features_df_test['class'].unique())
```

the output will be

```
Shape Of X_train: (149, 40)
Shape Of X_test: (63, 40)
Shape Of y_train: (149, 88)
Shape Of y_test: (63, 86)
Unique classes in training set: ['A_0' 'AS_0' 'B_0' 'A_1' 'AS_1' 'B_1' 'C_1' 'CS_1' 'D_1' 'DS_1' 'E_1'
 'F_1' 'FS_1' 'G_1' 'GS_1' 'A_2' 'AS_2' 'B_2' 'C_2' 'CS_2' 'D_2' 'DS_2'
 'E_2' 'F_2' 'FS_2' 'G_2' 'GS_2' 'A_3' 'AS_3' 'B_3' 'C_3' 'CS_3' 'D_3'
 'DS_3' 'E_3' 'F_3' 'FS_3' 'G_3' 'GS_3' 'A_4' 'AS_4' 'B_4' 'C_4' 'CS_4'
 'D_4' 'DS_4' 'E_4' 'F_4' 'FS_4' 'G_4' 'GS_4' 'A_5' 'AS_5' 'B_5' 'C_5'
 'CS_5' 'D_5' 'DS_5' 'E_5' 'F_5' 'FS_5' 'G_5' 'GS_5' 'A_6' 'AS_6' 'B_6'
 'C_6' 'CS_6' 'D_6' 'DS_6' 'E_6' 'F_6' 'FS_6' 'G_6' 'GS_6' 'A_7' 'AS_7'
 'B_7' 'C_7' 'CS_7' 'D_7' 'DS_7' 'E_7' 'F_7' 'FS_7' 'G_7' 'GS_7' 'C_8']
Unique classes in testing set: ['A_1' 'A_2' 'A_3' 'A_4' 'A_5' 'AS_1' 'AS_2' 'AS_3' 'AS_4' 'AS_5' 'B_1'
 'B_2' 'B_3' 'B_4' 'B_5' 'C_1' 'C_2' 'C_3' 'C_4' 'C_5' 'C_6' 'CS_1' 'CS_2'
 'CS_3' 'CS_4' 'CS_5' 'D_1' 'D_2' 'D_3' 'D_4' 'D_5' 'DS_1' 'DS_2' 'DS_3'
 'DS_4' 'DS_5' 'E_1' 'E_2' 'E_3' 'E_4' 'E_5' 'F_1' 'F_2' 'F_3' 'F_4' 'F_5'
 'FS_1' 'FS_2' 'FS_3' 'FS_4' 'FS_5' 'G_1' 'G_2' 'G_5' 'G_4' 'GS_1' 'GS_2'
 'GS_3' 'GS_4' 'GS_5' 'GS_7' 'C_8']
```

tell me if you need any more information

Edit2:the main error is in the title I think it says that there is shape mismatch between the model's output and the target labels (y_train). Also, the model is outputting a shape of (None, 86), while the target labels have a shape of (None, 88), and these shapes are incompatible. I do not understand why I got (None, 86) and not (None, 88) because I am sure that the labels in my dataset are ok.

**Update**:I have tried to put the train file as the test file and then the code went well, I guess after all the problem was in my dataset still do not know why I will see different datasets to see if it still works.
Thank you all!

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the error, for example, on which line did it occur, and even the full stack trace?

Comment: What is your error? Include it in the post please